# Postgresql. Есть 2 таблицы с данными

Tags: база-данных, postgresql

Postgresql. Есть таблица A с данными больше 1000 строк,а таблица B 3000 строк. у обоих название столбцов одинаковы: id, serv_id, type, ru, kg.

Мне надо обновить таблицу B именно столбцов type, ru, kg где serv_id одинакова.
Пробовал вот так:

```
UPDATE B
SET B.id = A.id,
B.serv_id = A.serv_id,
B.type = A.type,
B.ru = A.ru,
B.kg = A.kg
from A
where B.serv_id = A.serv_id
```

Выдает ошибку:

```
ERROR:  column "B" of relation "B" does not exist
LINE 1: UPDATE B SET B.id = A...
```

**Вопрос: 
   Как мне правильно сделать подскажите пожалуйста?
                                 ^**

Comment: Вас не смущает отсутствие пробела в процитированном в сообщении об ошибке фрагменте кода?

Comment: И зачем обновлять `B.serv_id = A.serv_id,`?

Comment: Это опечатка, на самом деле таблица по другому называется. Суть проблемы не этом же обновлять serv_id или нет не важно.

Comment: *Это опечатка, на самом деле таблица по другому называется.* Вот что... давайте-ка Вы не модель абы какую, а реальные DDL таблиц, реальный текст запроса, и реальное сообщение об ошибке. А ещё лучше - дополнительно пример данных для таблиц (3-5 записей), да желаемый результат.

Answer (score 0):

[Ваш запрос синтаксически ошибочен](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-update.html). Об этом прямо указано в документации:

> Do not include the table's name in the specification of a target column — for example, UPDATE table_name SET table_name.col = 1 is invalid.

`set column_name` - строго имя колонки обновляемой таблицы. Здесь нет и не может быть неоднозначности, `update` в postgresql обновляет строки только одной таблицы.

Синтаксис `set column_name.attribute =` - это про [композитные](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rowtypes.html) типы данные. При этом перед точкой стоит именно имя поля таблицы, в котором сохранены данные композитного типа. Поэтому вы и получаете ошибку о том, что поля такого не существует в этой таблице.

```
UPDATE B
SET id = A.id,
type = A.type,
ru = A.ru,
kg = A.kg
from A
where B.serv_id = A.serv_id
```